# How to Pause AnimationTimer for a Set Number of Seconds?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm currently working on a game made with JavaFX, and I was wondering how to pause AnimationTimer's for a set number of seconds? I tried using Thread.sleep, but it causes the entire window to freeze. Any help would be appreciated, I can provide code if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a `PauseTransition` that starts your timer after a certain amount of time has passed.

```
void pauseTimerForDuration(AnimationTimer timer, Duration duration) {
    PauseTransition pt = new PauseTransition(duration);
    pt.setOnFinished(event -> timer.start());

    timer.stop();
    pt.play();
}
```

*Note: This uses `javafx.util.Duration`, not `java.time.Duration`.*

If you want something you can reuse, then you can try a `Timeline`.

```
Timeline createPauseTimerTimeline(AnimationTimer timer, Duration duration) {
    return new Timeline(
            new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, event -> timer.stop()),
            new KeyFrame(duration, event -> timer.play())
    );
}
```

Then store the `Timeline` somewhere and call `playFromStart()` when you want to pause your timer.